# html multi line button not working in Chrome 48

Tags: html, google-chrome, button, multiline

I have the following code that worked 3 days ago until Chrome was upgraded to version 48.xxx
The code that worked before (chrome 46 and earlier) is:

`<input type='submit' value="3  &#x00A; Line  &#x00A; button" name="test">`

It works in IE.  Any ideas on how to get this working would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using this in some kind of form so I'd try something like this with the `<br/>` tag to avoid having to use &#x00A, though that's just personal preference:

```
<form method="get" action="your-form-action-here">
  <input type="submit" id="submit-form" hidden="true" />
</form>

<button for="submit-form">3<br/>Line<br/>Button</button>
```

Here's a fiddle of it for proof: https://jsfiddle.net/7rw55pss/

You can also do this with the button inside the form, like so:

```
<form method="get" action="your-form-action-here">
  <button>3<br/>Line<br/>Button</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you upvote or accept my answer then please? I'm trying to build up points so I can post and answer more. Thanks